# Can't login with phpseclib to my apache server

Tags: php, apache, shell, ssh, phpseclib

I have a php file inside my apache server that needs to run a shell script (also in the server). When I try the code in putty, it runs the shell script as intended. However, ssh is not able to connect, and the code below gives echos

> "Disconnected from server!" "Login Failed".

```
<?php

$script = "sudo bash /path/script.sh parameter";
set_include_path( __DIR__ .'/phpseclib/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 
get_include_path());
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
$ssh->enablePTY();

if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
    echo $ssh->isConnected() ? 'Connected but Not Logged In' : 'Disconnected From Server!';
    exit("\nLogin Failed");
}
$ssh->setTimeout(1);
$ssh->write($script."\n");
echo "Initialized Shell Script\n";
$ssh->read('password for $username:');
echo "Password Confirmation\n";
$ssh->write($password.'\n');
echo "Password Login\n";
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the server logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and `echo $ssh->getLogs();` after the failed `$ssh->login()`. Once you have those paste them in a pastebin.com link and add the link to your post. And post a comment reply saying that you've done so so I get notified that you did so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Net/SSH2 library supports debugging and error reporting. [The documentation for the library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_ssh_debug) describes how to debug the functions and view the errors.

You can call the function `$ssh->getErrors()` just before the `exit("\nLogin Failed");` function. It will return the errors.